# Control angularjs ui switch from external event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mqtt

I have a angularjs material ui switch. I want to change its status when an external event happens. This external event is a mqtt message received on one of the published topic. I am using node.js mqtt client running on a browser.

```
    <div ng-controller="SWCtrl">
        <md-switch ng-model="switch_status.sw1" aria-label="Switch" 
                   ng-change="onChange(switch_status.sw1)">
                Switch: {{ switch_status.sw1 }}
        </md-switch>
    </div>
```

The corresponding controller code;

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('SWCtrl', ['$scope',
        function ($scope, ) {
            $scope.switch_status = {
                sw1: true,
            };

            var mqtt_client = mqtt.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:3000');
            mqtt_client.subscribe('hello/world');
            mqtt_client.on('connect', function () {
                console.log("MQTT connected");
            });

            mqtt_client.on("message", function(topic, payload) {
                console.log([topic, payload].join(": "));
                if (topic === "hello/world" && payload.toString() === "switch on")
                {
                    console.log("message on");
                    $scope.switch_status.sw1 = true;
                }
                else if (topic === "hello/world" && payload.toString() === "switch off")
                {
                    console.log("message off");
                    $scope.switch_status.sw1 = false;
                }
            });

            $scope.onChange = function (sw_state) {
                if (sw_state === true) {
                    mqtt_client.publish('hello/world', 'switch on');
                }
                else if (sw_state === false) {
                    mqtt_client.publish('hello/world', 'switch off');
                }
            }
        }])
;
```

The code segment in the controller that gave me problem is here;

```
        mqtt_client.on("message", function(topic, payload) {
            console.log([topic, payload].join(": "));
            if (topic === "hello/world" && payload.toString() === "switch on")
            {
                console.log("message on");
                $scope.switch_status.sw1 = true;
            }
            else if (topic === "hello/world" && payload.toString() === "switch off")
            {
                console.log("message off");
                $scope.switch_status.sw1 = false;
            }
        });
```

When an external event happens, I want to change the switch status. How I did it was running the line of code below;

```
$scope.switch_status.sw1 = true;
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. How to make the switch change status when the external event happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try $scope.$apply() after the

```
$scope.switch_status.sw1 = true;
```

basically it wasn't an angular event so angular has no idea that the variable was even change. scope.apply will force another digest cycle